# How to add a click handler to a WPF Button in C++/CLR?

Tags: wpf, button, c++-cli, click, handler

In C#, I can do (*):

```
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Click += ButtonOnClick;
    :
    void ButtonOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // do something
    }
```

But in C++/CLI I can't do:

```
    Button ^ b = gcnew Button();
    b->Click += ButtonOnClick;
:
void ButtonOnClick(Object ^ sender, RoutedEventArgs ^ e)
{
    // do something
}
```

I get a compiler error complaing about the += ButtonOnClick:
2>.\blub.cpp(108) : error C3867: 'MyListBoxItem::ButtonOnClick': function call missing argument list; use '&MyListBoxItem::ButtonOnClick' to create a pointer to member

(The tip the compiler gives me doesn't work because it isn't a static method.)

What is the equivalent of (*) in C++/CLI ?

Thx
   Marc

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 b->Click += MAKE_DELEGATE( System::EventHandler, ButtonOnClick );
```

```
b->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &ButtonOnClick);
```

Comment: That gives me: error C2275: 'System::EventHandler' : illegal use of this type as an expression. Looking up MAKE_DELEGATE in msdn leads me to MFC Library Reference.
But I guess, I have to create a (.net) Delegate somehow - but I don't know how.

Comment: Oh, while that also doesn't work, it pointed me int he right direction. This is working:
b->Click += gcnew RoutedEventHandler(this, &ClassNameWhereTheButtonOnClickMethodIsIn::ButtonOnClick);
Thx :) - What shouldI mark as answer now?